# Multiple List Search with KeywordQuery

Tags: 2013, search, keywordquery

Trying to search specific lists by passing in the list paths.

```
path={0}+path={1}+path={2}
```

Is this possible?  Dose the above code look correct? No results are currently returning.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your query looks like, but wouldn't you want `(path={0} or path={1} or path={2}) and {searchterm}`? Give me all the {searchterms} that come from path 1 or path 2 or path 3?

Comment: i'm using "*" as a search term because i want all list items returned. Thanks for the correct syntax for multiple lists.

Comment: @EricAlexander - if I want all list items return would i use "*" as the search term?

Comment: you wouldn't necessarily have to if you are configuring a search results web part, just the paths will bring back everything

Comment: You will make your life significantly easier if you use Content Types. Using path is awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is: **Path:URL**

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(site);

string strQuery = "*";

foreach (string strPath in allLists)
{
   strQuery += String.Format(" Path:{0}", strPath);
}

keywordQuery.QueryText = strQuery + " (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary)";
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing about using `path` in your search queries is that it treats any value as an absolute path, meaning it doesn't support relative paths. You might see examples of it working though, but it is highly unlikely you will get the desired results.

It is best to make the search terms as specific as possible.
E.g. specify one or more content types; or include partial/full list titles (depending on requirements).